# Strange empty? recognition behavior

Tags: arrays, ruby, recursion, ternary-operator

I'm trying to make a method that returns an array from reading a 2d array spirally. I'm using recursion and then wanting to stop it when the parameter array passed in is empty.

```
@arr = []

def spiral(array)
  array.to_a.empty? ? true :  @arr << array.shift
  spiral(array.transpose.reverse)
end
```

However, when adding in the recursion line the empty method fails to recognize "[]" as being empty anymore and throws out a "stack level too deep" error which I assume is an infinite loop since it has no stopping criteria?

Comment: `array.to_a.empty? ? return :  @arr << array.shift`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to stop the recursion, your function needs to *return* when the desired condition is reached (or at least not call itself again). In your code, the function simply generates `true` but continue executing, calling itself at the end.

Try something like this:

```
@arr = []

def spiral(array)
  return @arr.flatten if array.to_a.empty?
  @arr << array.shift
  spiral(array.transpose.reverse)
end
```

Comment: Thanks so much, that was very quick! Yes I understand now.  In this case I would like to return @arr.flatten.